# Find the maximum of a & b in a set s = {1, 2, ... n } lesser than a certain value k

Tags: python, algorithm, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, boolean-logic

I was playing a bit with the Python language to solve a tutorial on HackerRank, available here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-bitwise-and

The gist of the challenge is to find the maximum of `a & b` where `a, b ∈ s`, `s` is the set defined such as: `s = {1, 2, ... n}` where `a < b`. Another condition is that `a & b < k` where `2 <= k <= n`.

The given inputs are `n` and `k`.

I managed to have an `O(n^2)` and `O(n)` solutions but I am struggling to come up with an `O(1)` solution.

For example, here is below a dummy `O(n^2)` solution:

```
def max_and(n, k):
    if (n < k) or (k < 2):
        raise ValueError()
    else:
        res = (0, 1, 0)
        for a in range(n + 1):
            for b in range(n + 1):
                if a < b:
                    temp = a & b
                    if res[2] < temp < k:
                        res = (a, b, temp)
        return res


for n in range(2, 10):
    print(["(n = {}, k = {}) = ".format(n, k) + str(max_and(n, k)) for k in range(2, n + 1)])
```

I noticed that the answer is always `k - 1` or `k - 2` which makes sense to me.

I think the idea is that the maximum of `a & b` is constraint to be lesser than `k` and since the logical and operator cannot output a number greater than b.

Some people on HackerRank came up with a O(1) solution but I don't really get how it actually works:

```
a = k - 1
b = (~a) & -(~a)

if (a | b) > n:
    print (a - 1)
else:
    print (a)
```

Especially why `b = (~a) & -(~a)`

I mean I get the point that it can be changed as

Comment: Curious about an answer as well. If a is an integer isn't the result of b always k?

Comment: I am interested in the answer also but can you tag it to boolean-logic too

Comment: @SeekAddo fixed =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `j = k - 1`, and let `unset_bit` be the lowest power of two such that `(j & unset_bit) == 0`.

If `(j | unset_bit) <= n`, then we pick `a = j` and `b = j | unset_bit` for the optimal value of `(a & b) == j`.

If `(j | unset_bit) > n`, then no possible choice of `a` and `b` will give us `(a & b) == j`. We simply don't have two numbers to pick with all the necessary bits set. Since an even `j` would have given us `(j | unset_bit) == j+1 <= n`, we must have `j` odd. Then picking `a = j - 1` and `b = j` gives us `(a & b) == j - 1`, the highest possible value.

---

The code you saw on HackerRank implements this idea. In the code you found, their `a` is our `j`, and their `b` is our `unset_bit`, computed through some bit twiddling tricks. I've used `j` and `unset_bit` instead of `a` and `b` because you've already used those letters for other meanings.